# JSONP error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Tags: javascript, html, json, jsonp

I am trying to get a json encoded object from [here](http://wcischeduleapp.com/app/get.php) but I keep on receiving the following error "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token : ". I was wondering what is causing this error and what I could do to fix it. Thanks to anyone who can help. Here's my code.

```
<script>
function mycallback(answer){
var stuff = JSON.parse(answer);
alert(stuff);
console.log(stuff);
}
</script>
<script src="http://www.wcischeduleapp.com/app/get.php?callback=mycallback"></script>
```

Comment: No callback is added to the JSON in that link, so it's not valid JSONP.

Comment: I'd recommend you read the API documentation (if it exists) or contact the developer (if it doesn't) to verify that they actually support JSONP and to verify that 'callback' is the correct name for the JSONP parameter this service expects.

Answer (score 0):

The way JSONP works is that `answer` is already an object, not a JSON string any more.

So just `console.log(answer);` will work just fine.

Comment: On top of that, the url in that example doesn't call any function... its just returning json